# Multilanguage mails

Tags: 7, emails, i18n-l10n

We have built a site with multi language support in English and German languages. Now we need to set drupal default mails like login reg. mails, forget password mails in both the languages. The users using German site will need to get German mails and vice versa for English users.

So we have changed German mail content under Account setting -> Email of german(DE) Website. and i had checked the English website(EN) Version, its shows me the german mail Content. The Mail content are synchronizing while updating in one language version of the website... 
what i need to do to fix this one?

Comment: Are you using the i18n and variable modules to manage the e-mail translation?  These two modules can be used together to send multilingual e-mails out-of-the-box.

Comment: yes, we already installed i18n and variable modules, But please update me how to set the mails in multilingual format.

Answer (score 16):

Ok, here's how to do this using i18n and variable:

1. Visit "Variables" under "Multilingual settings". (/admin/config/regional/i18n/variable)
2. Under "User e-mails", check all e-mails that you wish to translate and click "Save configuration".
3. Go to the e-mail configuration page. (/admin/config/people/accounts)
4. By default, the e-mails will be displayed in the default language.  To translate the e-mails you selected in Step 2 above, choose a language from the **There are multilingual variables in this form)** box at the top of the page.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, if I select "Italiano" in the box at the top of the page, then change "Thank you" with "Grazie", after saved configuration, "Grazie" is shown for both English and Italian language..